# Общеотрицательное или частноотрицательное предложение?

Tags: семантика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое это предложение: общеотрицательное или частноотрицательное?
**Один и тот же человек не может быть конкурсантом более двух раз подряд.**

Я хочу это определить, чтобы понять смысл: один и тот же человек вообще не может быть конкурсантом более двух раз подряд (только два раза подряд и больше нельзя быть конкурсантом) или всё-таки после перерыва может.

Answer (score 1):

Данное утверждение не исключает *произвольного* количества участий в конкурсе - при выполнении условия: если человек участвовал в конкурсе два раза подряд (= без пропуска *очередного* конкурса между случаями своего участия), то следующий за этим конкурс он обязательно пропустит, а позже при желании может на том же условии участвовать в тех же конкурсах любое число раз. На точно таком же условии можно баллотироваться в президенты РФ.

Answer (score 0):

Если "подряд", то ясное дело, что после перерыва можно. В противном случае автор текста неправильно изложил мысль.